# How to use Alias name of inner query as a column to get record that have no data or is null in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

i tried to use like this but its not giving proper result that i want

```
SELECT SubCategoryName, 
       SubCategoryId,
      (SELECT TOP (1) Image
         FROM PostImage
        WHERE (PostDesignId LIKE ( 
                                   SELECT TOP (1) PostDesignId 
                                     FROM PostDesign 
                                    WHERE (SubCategoryId = SC.SubCategoryId) 
                                          OR (SubCategoryId2 = SC.SubCategoryId)
                                  )
               )
       ) AS ImageName 
  FROM SubCategory AS SC 
 WHERE ImageName IS NOT NULL
```

Please help me....

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use aliases from the `SELECT` clause in your `WHERE` clause because of the logical order the query is processed. For more details see: http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sq.SubCategoryName,
    sq.SubCategoryId,
    sq.ImageName
FROM
(
    SELECT SubCategoryName, 
       SubCategoryId,
      (SELECT TOP (1) Image
         FROM PostImage
        WHERE (PostDesignId LIKE ( 
                                   SELECT TOP (1) PostDesignId 
                                     FROM PostDesign 
                                    WHERE (SubCategoryId = SC.SubCategoryId) 
                                          OR (SubCategoryId2 = SC.SubCategoryId)
                                  )
               )
       ) AS ImageName 
  FROM SubCategory AS SC 
) as sq
WHERE sq.ImageName IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark this as the answer if you are satisfied with it.